# Why is my htaccess file not working as expected?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Working witch autodiscover and Outlook and others mail clients, it seems that everybody make what he want about case.

For exemple, last Outlook client search for autodiscover/autodiscover.xml when other search for Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

So, I wanted to have a rewriterul to redirect on my php whatever original URL.
He is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^[Aa]utodiscover/Autodiscover.xml autoconfig-mail.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^mail/config-v1.1.xml autoconfig-mail.php [NC,L]
```

This is OK on "Autodiscover.xml" but not on the first "autodiscover" in URL. Why?

According to [https://htaccess.madewithlove.com](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/)/ it will work...

Thank you

Tried to add QSA, Remove or replace some options, nevermind...

Comment: Please clarify which _exact_ URL is not working as intended.

Comment: Well, your rule contains _two_ characters "a" that according to your description could occur in upper or lower case. Your rule handles only the first character, not the one after the slash.

Comment: @CBroe : the URL is https://autodiscover.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

Comment: @arkascha : Yes, but here, it's the SECOND "a" who is working well (a or A), but the first work only if it's a A (uppercase)

Comment: I suggest you enable rewrite logging.